# Vim trick - how to view directory as a "folder"?

Tags: vim

I was working in the ubuntu terminal and accidentally "vim-ed" to a folder instead of cd-ing to it. Somehow this displayed a window that displayed the directory's contents as if it were a folder on the desktop. So how do I do this again?

Answer (score 6):

By default, vim opens directories into a buffer using the built-in `netrw` plugin. See `:help netrw` for information. Additionally, many users like other plugins like [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/) to edit directories. You can edit a folder using

```
:e /path/to/directory
```

or by opening it directly when you start vim:

```
vim /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is the directory:

```
/some/directory/on/filesystem/
```

You just `vim` the directory:

```
vim /some/directory/on/filesystem
```

In *nix all directories are actually files, and are handled in a similar way. Therefore it is possible to directly edit them. Note that stackoverflow may not be the best place for this question.

Comment: @Brian It has nothing to do with the fact that directories are files. It is built-in netrw plugin which does the job: if you do `vim -u NONE .` all you will get is an error message.